# How to make sure face is not ugly without any mirror/smart phone?

Tags: personal-care, comfort

The **though** of the presence of food items on lips or near to them after eating, presence of mucus after bathing or while suffering with cold bothers a lot.

Sometimes I realize about their presence after talking with many people and spending time with them but **no one tells about it**, which makes me worry.

Due to such worse experiences, I made it as habit of checking consistently with hands, which is also not good.

If room has mirror and person has smart phone, then it is easy to check and fix. But it is not always possible

ex: while eating, inside class room, during discussion etc.,

I need an idea to be confident any time without such bothering.

Comment: Also train yourself to be confident of your appearance for at least half an hour after you check your reflection, unless you eat or something.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Find yourself **a wristwatch or bracelet** with a polished chrome or mirrored surface. A pair of **reflective sunglasses** will work in a pinch.

This will allow you to look at yourself inconspicuously without drawing too much attention to yourself by constantly reaching into your pocket or backpack.

[image] [image] [image]

[image] [image]